# Info windows doesnt appear in google maps and angular 12

Tags: angular, google-maps

Im trying to setup a custom info windows when makes click over icon, I changed image in ubication, but not appears the little window.

I found a blog with part of solution, but I dont have complete the infowindow part.
Maybe im forgetting some or make a mistake, please check and comment.
Thanks for help, im old but noob/junior in javascript/angular/typescript.

Component code:

```
  // Google maps
  
  @ViewChild(GoogleMap, { static: false }) map: GoogleMap
  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow;
         
openInfo(
  
  marker: MapMarker, content) {
  this.infoContent = content
  this.infoWindow.open(marker);
}
   zoom = 6
  center: google.maps.LatLngLiteral
  options: google.maps.MapOptions = {
    zoomControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
    maxZoom: 20,
    minZoom: 1,
  }
  
  ngOnInit() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    this.center = {
    lat: -36.78817,
    lng: -59.8347,
    }
   })
   
  }

  
click(event: google.maps.MapMouseEvent) {
  console.log(event)
}
  iconBase = "assets/img/icons/"

 infoContent: '<div><p>hola</p></div>'

  
  markers = [{

    position:{
    lat: -36.78817,
    lng:-59.8347,
  },
    visible: true,
    opacity: 0.0,

    label: {
    color: 'black',
    text: ' ',
    },

    title: 'Marker title',
    options: {
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: this.iconBase + 'ypf-logo-mapa.png',
    }
  },
  {

    position:{
    lat: -34.660929000000003,
    lng: -58.444881000000002,
  },
    visible: true,
    opacity: 1.0,

    label: {
    color: 'white',
    text: ' ',
    },

    title: 'Marker title',
    options: {
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    icon: this.iconBase + 'axion-logo-mapa.png',
    }
  }
]
```

Html code:

```
 <google-map
                            (mapClick)="click($event)" 
                            [center]="center"
                            [options]="options"
                            height="350px"
                            width="100%"
                            [zoom]="zoom">
                            
                          
                                <map-marker [clickable]="true"
                                 #markerElem
                                 *ngFor="let marker of markers"
                                 [position]="marker.position"
                                 [label]="marker.label"
                                 [title]="marker.title"
                                 [options]="marker.options"
                                 (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem)">
                                 <map-info-window >Hello Google Maps
                                </map-info-window>
                                </map-marker>
                               
                            </google-map>                              
                             
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `<map-info-window >Hello Google Maps</map-info-window>` outside of `<map-marker>` tag:

```
                      <google-map (mapClick)="click($event)" 
                        [center]="center"
                        [options]="options"
                        height="350px"
                        width="100%"
                        [zoom]="zoom">
                        
                            <map-marker [clickable]="true"
                             #markerElem
                             *ngFor="let marker of markers"
                             [position]="marker.position"
                             [label]="marker.label"
                             [title]="marker.title"
                             [options]="marker.options"
                             (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem)"></map-marker>

                           <map-info-window >Hello Google Maps</map-info-window>
                       </google-map>                              
                         
                    </div>
```